# Translating strings in laravel

Tags: laravel, translate, laravel-9

Im triying to make an error string translatable, and normally i use `{{__('x')}}` to make a translating string, but since a `@error` already contains a atribute string to display the error (`@error('name') is-invalid @enderror`) it won't allow me to put a translate string on the atribute, is there any way to translate the atribute of the error message?

Comment: did you modified your local language while serving that request?

Comment: yes, all the other translatable strings work. but im not able to add a translatable string to the @error string